# Extension preview disapeared since WP 4.5.2

Tags: plugins, dashboard

Since the last Wordpress update, I can't read new version notes when trying to update a plugin in my dashboard. 
[image]

The same thing happens when I try to read an plugin's details.

How can I fix that ?

**Edit:**

Here's what I get from my browser's console when trying to view a plugin's details:

[image]

Comment: No script errors or network errors in your browser's debug console? No errors from WordPress? Does right-click, open in new tab show the details correctly?

Comment: @Rup I looked at the debug console and I noticed that I have some errors (14). Most of them are `net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT` or websocket errors (403). Opening the link in a new tab works well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your answer @rarst. The issue came from my nginx configuration.

I just had to change `add_header X-Frame-Options deny;` to `add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN" always;`

Answer (score 4):

Your error log does tell you the reason, it's the part about:

> Refused to display ... in a frame because it set to 'X-Frame-Origin' to 'SAMEORIGIN,DENY'

And the reason for that is the one about "conflicting values" before it.

WordPress core only sends `SAMEORIGIN` value in admin screens, via `send_frame_options_header()`. So `DENY` is coming from elsewhere and is what messes things up.

Search your sources for `DENY` and inquire with hosting support if it's something web server might be configured to add.